# Designated initializers for variable arguments

Tags: c, struct, minecraft, variadic-functions

I'm writing a text-based Minecraft bot, mainly to (try to) annoy some players/admins and check out the internals of the [Minecraft protocol](http://wiki.vg/Protocol).

Anyway, I'm still in the design phase and writing functions for sending and receiving packets. The declarations look like this right now:

```
int send_packet(int sock, con_state_t state, send_packet_t ptype, ...);
int recv_packet(int sock, con_state_t state, recv_packet_t ptype, ...);
```

<sub>(I'm planning on adding `typedef`s for error and socket types, both `int`s.)</sub>

So far, so good. I know variable arguments are type-unsafe but enable me to write better code as opposed to `struct`s. I can write code such as this (the `send_packet` function):

```
/* BTW: I had to decide between structs passed as void* to imitate
 * inheritance and variable-length arguments.
 * Both are equally type-unsafe but variable-length arguments offer the
 * significant advantage of portably iterating over them. Therefore, I can
 * implement a packet-independent packet sending function without remarkable
 * struggle or packet-specific functions, which would be QUITE a hassle.
 * A drawback is that for every argument from the variable-length arguments,
 * data has to be pushed on the stack, so the stack frame grows linearly
 * to the argument count. Not so with a struct; only the address of it had to
 * be passed.
 * (Is variable-length argument the right term at all? I deduced it from
 * variable-length array...)
 */
int send_packet(int sock, send_packet_t ptype, ...) {
    va_list fields;
    uint8_t data[0];    /* TODO: replace 0 by something like PACK_MAX_LEN
                                          * or so! */

    /* TODO: as mentioned above, data should actually have the size of
     * PACK_MAX_LEN. because this might be very big, you could use some
     * dynamic memory allocation mechanism! same goes for string_t, chat_t,
     * and all similar data types. */

    uint8_t* data_it = data;

    /* TODO: ADD PREPENDING OF PACKET ID AND PACKET LENGTH HERE! */
    /* TODO: this function isn't finished. add some code, man! resuming the
     * above comment. */

    /* TODO: add support for legacy server list ping! (packet id = 0xfe) */

    /* TODO: for more complex data types: add code to convert from
     * simple data types to these complex ones like fix_varint_t to
     * varint_t! */

    va_start(fields, ptype);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sp_structs[ptype].len; ++i) {
        /* Jeez, I hope my code is understandable... */
        switch (sp_structs[ptype].fields[i]) {
        case map_boolean:
            cpy_data_sp(boolean_t);
            break;
        case map_byte:
            cpy_data_sp(byte_t);
            break;
        case map_ubyte:
            cpy_data_sp(ubyte_t);
            break;
        case map_short:
            cpy_data_sp(short_t);
            break;
        case map_ushort:
            cpy_data_sp(ushort_t);
            break;
        case map_int:
            cpy_data_sp(int_t);
            break;
        case map_long:
            cpy_data_sp(long_t);
            break;
        case map_chat:
            cpy_data_sp(chat_t);
            break;
        case map_string:
            cpy_data_sp(string_t);
            break;
        case map_varint:
            /* TODO: maybe write a macro to generalize wr_varint
             * and wr_varlong. */

            fix_varint_t fix = va_arg(fields, fix_varint_t);
            data_it += wr_varint(data_it, fix);
            break;
        case map_varlong:
            fix_varlong_t fix = va_arg(fields, fix_varlong_t);
            data_it += wr_varlong(data_it, fix);
            break;
        /*case map_chunk:
            cpy_data_sp(chunk_t);
            break;*/
        }
    }

/*
    if (sock_send(sock, data, packet_len) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
*/
    va_end(packet);

    return 0;
}
```

I just want to show you that, so you get why variable arguments are better here.
With `struct`s, the function prototype would look as follows:

```
 int send_packet(int sock, con_state_t state, send_packet_t ptype, void* pack);
```

`pack` points to the `struct` here. Now we could deduce the packet type with `ptype` but we **cannot iterate conveniently over the fields** as mentioned in the first comment in the above code.

Everyone using that function has to know the exact order of the arguments or undefined behavior might occur. `struct`s are nice here because of *designated initializers*, which enable order-independent member initialization.
**Can you think of some way to emulate that for variable arguments?**
Maybe some `va_list` magic? It should be strictly-conforming, though.

**Note:** using C++ already came to my mind, which would solve all my problems, but I want to do this in nice, standard C99 with some C11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use key/value-pairs instead of positioned values:

```
 int func(int argc, ...) {

 }
```

and call it like

```
func(3, 
         P_NAME,    "John",
         P_SURNAME, "Myers", 
         P_AGE,     10
    );
```

or use a 0-value as terminator to avoid argc.

Comment: Nice idea! Only drawback is that the number of arguments passed is doubled and thus more data has to be passed. Do you have any code where this is actively used?

Comment: No, I haven't used this yet. The stack size needed for the parameters will be about double size, this is correct. But if you do not recurse with such functions (or code for platforms with very restricted resources), this is probably not noticable in practice.